# Subgroup of free abelian group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, free-abelian-group

Let $G$ be a free abelian group of finite rank. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ such that 
$$ G = H + pG$$
for some prime number $p$. How can I show that $[G:H]<\infty$?

My proof is like this;

> $G \cong \mathbb{Z}^{n}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, thus $pG = \{ (p{i_1},p{i_2}, \cdots, p{i_n}) : i_{1}, \cdots i_{n} \in \mathbb{N} \}.$
>   Thus, by Euclidean algorithm, for any $g= (a_{1}, \cdots, a_n) \in G$, $\exists (p{i_1},p{i_2}, \cdots, p{i_n}) \in pG$ such that 
>   $$g-(p{i_1},p{i_2}, \cdots, p{i_n}) = (r_{1}, \cdots, r_{n})$$
>   where $0 <= r_i < p$ for any $0 <= i <=n$. By the condition $G =H+pG$, $(r_1 , \cdots, r_{n}) \in H$. Thus $$H = <\{ (r_{1},\cdots, r_{n}): 0<= r_{i}<p \}>.$$
>   Therefore, H=G implies $[G:H]=1$

Is this proof right? Or could you give me some idea?

Comment: You should either use additive notation or multiplicative notation (in which the hypothesis would read $G=HG^p$).

Comment: @egreg Thank you. I changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use additive notation, which is implied by the question.

Consider
$$
p(G/H)=(pG+H)/H=G/H
$$
Hence $K=G/H$ is a finitely generated abelian group with the property that $pK=K$.

Write $K=F\oplus C$, where $F$ is free and $C$ is finite, by the fundamental theorem on finitely generated abelian groups.

Comment: Could you explain why the first equality holds? I think $p(G/H) = p((pG+H)/H)$ is right.

Comment: @user124697 In general, $p(G/H)=(pG+H)/H$; then you can apply the hypothesis that $pG+H=G$.